Cierre de un winform con verificación de un TextBox
Utilizo visual studio 2022 con c# y postgresql, en ambiente Net Core 8.
Tengo un winform con un control TextBox, llamado idcliente dónde se carga el id del cliente y un botón (Salir) para cerrar el formulario, además de otros controles. El idcliente tiene la propiedad Leave donde se verifica que no puede salir de dicho control si está vacío.
El problema es que al presionar el botón de cierre de la ventana no es posible hacerlo por la propiedad Leave del idcliente. He intentado crear una variable protegida llamada CierraForm en false y asignarle true en la propiedad Close() y en el FormClosing().
Pero lo raro es que al presionar la X de la ventana se cierra sin problema, no así desde el botón de cierre. Les adjunto el código. Muchas gracias.
    private bool CierraForm = false;

    private void idcliente_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(idcliente.Text) && !CierraForm)
        {
            if (!Lee_Empresa())
            {
                Mensajes.ShowBox("El código de entidad ingresado no existe.", "Advertencia", "Aceptar", "");
                idcliente.Text = string.Empty;
                idcliente.Focus();
            }
        }
    }

    private void Salir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CierraForm = true;
        Close();
    }

    private void Facturacion_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dgv.Rows.Count == 0)  //false: cierra aunque haya cambios
        {
            CierraForm = true;
            e.Cancel = false;
        }
        else
        {
            string Mensa = "Se han detectado cambios. Si cierra la ventana se perderán los datos modificados. \n ¿Desea continuar?";
            string mensaje = Mensajes.ShowBox(Mensa, "Advertencia", "SI", "NO");
            if (mensaje == "S") //continúa cerrando la ventana
            {
                CierraForm = true;
                e.Cancel = false;
            }
            else
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
        }
    }


Lo único que debes hacer es desvincular el método asociado al evento Leave, para esto vas al evento clic del botón y pones:
idcliente.Leave -= idcliente_Leave;


El problema persiste, porque idcliente tiene el foco y al hacer clic sobre el botón Salir, prevalece la función Leave de idcliente.

private void id_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (!CierraForm)
{
if (!Lee_Empresa())
{
Mensajes.ShowBox("El código de entidad ingresado no existe.", "Advertencia", "Aceptar", "");
id.Text = string.Empty;
id.Focus();
}
}
}
    private void Salir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        id.Leave -= id_Leave!;
        CierraForm = true;
        Close();
    }


Un problema que tienen los proyectos Winforms es que es complicado configurar el boton cerrar nativo, o los eventos de cierre de Form.
Para ello lo mejor es crear uno propio y esconder el nativo con la propiedad BorderStyle.None de los Forms.
Allí, directamente sobre el evento Click del boton de cerrar creado por uno mismo, puedes condicionar el cierre o no cierre de los formularios con simples sentencias if, else, else if.
Seguro habran personas que te den soluciones más completas o distintas, pero a mi parecer, es la solución mas sencilla.
No se si mi respuesta te servirá, pero es lo que yo haría para evitarme dolores de cabezas sobre ese punto.

el problema está en que al hacer clic sobre el botón Salir, prevalece la función Leave del control idcliente que evita que se ejecute el código de la función Salir, por lo tanto no se cierra la ventana. Solo se cierra con el botón salir si el idcliente posee datos. Debería haber una forma que permita cerrar la ventana a través del botón Salir a pesar del Leave de idcliente. Pero vuelvo a aclarar que con la X de la ventana se cierra correctamente.
